# best way to module.exports a value of an async await function

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

So i was just reading the nodemailer documentation for the first time and in their example at the website

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });
   
  return transporter;
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

but I wanted to put that coding in a folder and only export **transporter** out to be able to use it in my routes files.

what is the best way to be able to export it out without having to run an await every time before using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is obtained asynchronously, you cannot export the final value (with current versions of node.js).  At the time of the exports, the value is not yet known so all you can really do is export the promise and anyone who wants the value will have to use `await` or `.then()` on the promise to get the value.

There are proposals to support asynchronous exports so the loader itself will block and wait for asynchronous values (to make problems like this easier), but that is not yet available for use.

Another thing I have occasionally done is to not launch the meat of the app until some asynchronous value has been obtained and placed into a variable where it can be retrieved synchronously.  If your code is a server, that would usually involve not starting the server until the async value is available and stuffed into a variable.  Thus, no request handler can occur before the async value is in that variable and it can then essentially be used synchronously.